# HOW to relocation if a query doesnt exist

Tags: php, mysql

if a query what exist http://localhost/page.php?pid=**first-page** is open me, it is work, but if i write http://localhost/page.php?pid=**second-page**  and second-page doesnt exist it still open a page and  give this error because doesnt find...

I understand why give me this error, but i dont know how to relocation the url if a some write a wrong query

```
session_start();
require "conx.php";
// Determine which page ID to use in our query below ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
    $pageid = preg_replace('[^a-z0-9_]', '', $_GET['pid']);
    }   
    // $tag is now santized and ready for database queries here
// Query the body section for the proper page
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT pagebody FROM pages WHERE linklabel = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $pageid);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    // do something with $row
    $body = $row["pagebody"];   
}
```

so i how i can relocation the url address if a the query doesnt exist??

Comment: *Notice: Undefined variable: titlu* - ok, so you obviously are trying to use a variable somewhere that has yet been defined.

Comment: If You detect that the page doesn't exist, You may relocate to another page using HTTP's `Location` header.

Comment: use a conditional `isset()` and/or `empty()`. Your question's short on relevant code though and looks to be pagination-related.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i said if you paid attention.... i understand why give me a error and i didnot ask for how to fix that, i asked for other this... how to Relocation if a query doesnt exist, and i figured up how to do that. anyway thanks for you tried to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to redirect (*relocation the URL address*) the user when the result is empty (*the query doesn't exist*), please try this:

```
//If the query return empty result redirect the user to 404 page !
if(!$result->num_rows) {
    header('Location: /404.php'); //Change it to your page
    exit;
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I doubt that's what the question/issue is about. However, let's have the OP decide.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's the main question or the only question :D **so i how i can relocation the url address if a the query doesnt exist??**

Comment: TBH, I have no idea at this point as the question is too unclear for my taste. An undefined variable that hasn't been posted, will more than likely get closed based on it.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Yes, the error is on line **82** . However, the code above is way less than that @Fred-ii- !

Comment: @JayBlanchard the main question is **i how i can relocation the url address if a the query doesnt exist??** and the code is commented. Here, a **good answer** would be the PHP Manual !!!

Comment: @Fred-ii- i said i know why was gave me a error, other was the problem and Ismail help me, the code works fine, thank you man

Comment: @JayBlanchard Please remove the duplicated mark and read the question carefully !

Comment: I removed the duplicate mark! Please stop shouting as it is unnecessary! P.S. I read the question carefully the first time and until the OP made clarification the duplicate was correct.